# Ruby ancestors methods issue

Tags: ruby, object, singleton

consider the following example:

```
module M
end

class C
  include M
end

c = C.new
p c.singleton_class.ancestors
```

the output is: `[#<Class:#<C:0x000055b6b069c5f0>>, C, M, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

but now if we include the module in singleton_class of object c as following

```
class << c
  include M 
  p ancestors
end
```

the output is: `[#<Class:#<C:0x000055b6b069c5f0>>, C, M, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

But `The well-grounded Rubyist` books say it should be as follows in chapter 13 `Object individual`:

`[#<Class:#<C:0x000055b6b069c5f0>>, M, C, M, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

Comment: What's your actual question? And what version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question we need to understand how include works.
`Module#include`

> Invokes #append_features on each parameter in reverse order.

`Module#append_features`

> add the constants, methods, and module variables of this module to mod if this module has not already been added to mod or one of its ancestors.

If you swap the order in which you include the module you will have the expected result

```rb
module M
end

class C
end

c = C.new

p c.singleton_class.ancestors
# -> [#<Class:#<C:0x000056285c79a678>>, C, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
class << c
  include M 
end

p c.singleton_class.ancestors
# -> [#<Class:#<C:0x000056285c79a678>>, M, C, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
# M is not in the ancestors of the class C is ancestors of the singleton class

class C
  include M
end

p c.singleton_class.ancestors
# -> [#<Class:#<C:0x000056285c79a678>>, M, C, M, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
# The include statement put M as first ancestors of C
```

If we change the order

```rb
module M
end

class C
end

c = C.new

p c.singleton_class.ancestors
# [#<Class:#<C:0x000055b278d8a290>>, C, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

class C
  include M
end

p c.singleton_class.ancestors
# [#<Class:#<C:0x000055b278d8a290>>, C, M, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
# M is ancestor of C and of the singleton class #C

class << c
  include M 
end

p c.singleton_class.ancestors
# [#<Class:#<C:0x000055b278d8a290>>, C, M, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
# M is not included
```